# Bind service using nested class

Tags: android, bindservice

I am following tutorial for bind service,this is my code

server

```
public class Server extends Service {

IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public Server getServerInstance() {
        return Server.this;
    }
}

public String getTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    return mDateFormat.format(new Date());
 }
}
```

client

```
public class Client extends Activity {

boolean mBounded;
Server mServer;
TextView text;
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            text.setText(mServer.getTime());
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Server.class);
    bindService(mIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
};

ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Toast.makeText(Client.this, "Service is disconnected", 1000).show();
        mBounded = false;
        mServer = null;
    }

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Toast.makeText(Client.this, "Service is connected", 1000).show();
        mBounded = true;
        LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mServer = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mBounded) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBounded = false;
    }
};
}
```

Its working fine.

If i change

```
LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mServer = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();
```

to

```
mServer = new Server();
```

It also work fine.

so what is actual need of creating nested LocalBinder class in the Server class and create getServerInstance() method for getting reference of it, if we can directly initialize its object using traditional java method by new keyword, i have seen it also in some other examples.I can't make out it, Any expert can help me?

Comment: Sevice class have own lifecicle. Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html